# create zoom functionality when we click on sign whole page get zoom and when we click - sign it get zoom out.

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create zoom functionality when we click on + sign whole page get zoom and when we click - sign it get zoom out in javascript or in CSS. How it is possible? It will be used in php. It also show Zooming %.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently there is zoom property in CSS3.](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/)

You can apply it to body and it should zoom the whole page.

Comment: Can you share me that code. I am not able to find out this code. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of bad user experience to zoom in and out a whole page. Users who really have low vision and challenges know already where and how to do it in the browser. Those who don't have any, well they would be shocked a bit when the entire page gets bigger or smaller.

My advise: just try to analyze what exactly you what to zoom in-out, if it is text area, just set bigger font size with js, if its image, just stretch it with js, it if is block, svg etc., just set bigger parameters.

P.S.: the `zoom` property in not cross-browser and has weird behavior. But you can combine it with the `transform` property to make a more or less cross-browser solution.

Comment: I have set all these property for which you are saying. But Client require to zoom in and Out to whole page. + and - sign should be set on top as like menu button. Please Help me.

Comment: There is no way to get access to browsers + | - buttons with javascript, you got to emulate this behavior by changing elements in your page. By transform property, enlarging font-sizes, changing dimensions for each needful element.